# Proving convexity of non-smooth function using smooth approximation

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite, non-smooth-analysis

Suppose we are given a positive semi-definite matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and suppose we define the function $\sigma_{s}(\boldsymbol{x}) = [\max \lbrace x_1, s \rbrace, \cdots, \max \lbrace x_n, s \rbrace]^T$ that takes an input vector $\boldsymbol{x}$ and outputs a vector where $\max \lbrace x_i, s \rbrace$ is the $i^{th}$ component. I would like to show that the following function is convex for all $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any fixed $s \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \sigma_s(\boldsymbol{x})^T C \sigma_s(\boldsymbol{x})$$

I initially tried to go about this using common approaches for reasoning about convexity, namely by looking at the composition going on here and noticing that various of the functions in the composition are convex or whatnot. However, since I wish for $C$ to be an arbitrary positive semi-definite matrix, I have been running into issues using the typical techniques I am familiar with due to the non-smooth properties of $\sigma_s(\boldsymbol{x})$.

I have gone a different route that I feel may not technically work, but I will present it for you to comment on. Namely, one can observe (with some manipulations) that $\max\lbrace x, s \rbrace = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{t} \log \left(\exp(ts) + \exp(tx)\right) = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \alpha_s^t(x)$, where $\alpha_s^t(x) = \frac{1}{t} \log \left(\exp(ts) + \exp(tx)\right)$. My thought was to fix some arbitrary $t > 0$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and then define $\bar{\sigma}_s^t(\boldsymbol{x})$ as
$$\bar{\sigma}_s^t(\boldsymbol{x}) = \left[\alpha_s^t(x_1), \cdots, \alpha_s^t(x_n)\right]^T$$

and use this new definition to show that the below function is convex
$$\bar{f}^t(\boldsymbol{x}) = \bar{\sigma}_s^t(\boldsymbol{x})^T C \bar{\sigma}_s^t(\boldsymbol{x})^T$$

We can notice that now the function is smooth and so we can reason about whether this function is convex by computing the hessian and seeing if it is positive semi-definite. If one goes through some calculations, we can find that the hessian of $\bar{f}$ is
$$H_{\bar{f}^t}(\boldsymbol{x}) = 2J_{\bar{\sigma}_s^t}(\boldsymbol{x}) C J_{\bar{\sigma}_s^t}(\boldsymbol{x})$$

where $J_{\bar{\sigma}_s^t}(\boldsymbol{x})$ is the jacobian of $\bar{\sigma}_s^t$ and is symmetric and diagonal, in this case, due to the element-wise nature of $\bar{\sigma}_s^t$. This representation for the Hessian can be readily shown to be positive semi-definite, namely by observing that for any $\boldsymbol{x}$ and any $\boldsymbol{u} \neq \vec{0}$, we have that
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{u}^T H_{\bar{f}^t}(\boldsymbol{x}) \boldsymbol{u} &= 2\boldsymbol{u}^T J_{\bar{\sigma}_s^t}(\boldsymbol{x}) C J_{\bar{\sigma}_s^t}(\boldsymbol{x}) \boldsymbol{u} \\
&= 2 \left(J_{\bar{\sigma}_s^t}(\boldsymbol{x}) \boldsymbol{u} \right)^T C \left(J_{\bar{\sigma}_s^t}(\boldsymbol{x}) \boldsymbol{u}\right) \\
&\geq 0 \tag{$C$ is positive semi-definite}
\end{align}

Thus, we find that $\bar{f}^t$ is convex for a fixed $t > 0$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Since these were chosen arbitrarily, it should imply that the function is convex for any $t > 0$ and all $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Now my issue is the following: as I take $t \rightarrow \infty$, $\bar{f} \rightarrow f$ and this seems to imply to me that $f$ is convex for any $s \in \mathbb{R}$.. but clearly the non-smoothness arises for non-finite $t$ so I am not sure if this implication is really correct.

If anyone has any comments on my reasoning or other suggestions, I would appreciate it.

**Update**

After thinking more about it, I think I found a way to rationalize this. For a fixed $t > 0$, the above work proved that
\begin{align*}
    \bar{f}^t\left( \alpha \boldsymbol{u} + (1 - \alpha) \boldsymbol{v} \right) \leq \alpha \bar{f}^t\left(\boldsymbol{u}\right) + (1 - \alpha)\bar{f}^t\left( \boldsymbol{v} \right) \tag{$\forall \alpha \in [0,1]$}
\end{align*}

If I take the limit on both sides as $t \rightarrow \infty$, we can obtain
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\bar{f}^t\left( \alpha \boldsymbol{u} + (1 - \alpha) \boldsymbol{v} \right) &\leq \alpha \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \bar{f}^t\left(\boldsymbol{u}\right) + (1 - \alpha) \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \bar{f}^t\left( \boldsymbol{v} \right) \tag{$\forall \alpha \in [0,1]$} \\
    \implies f\left( \alpha \boldsymbol{u} + (1 - \alpha) \boldsymbol{v} \right) &\leq \alpha f\left(\boldsymbol{u}\right) + (1 - \alpha)f\left( \boldsymbol{v} \right) \tag{$\forall \alpha \in [0,1]$}
\end{align*}

which, unless I am doing something illegal here, should imply that $f$ is indeed convex.

**Update 2**

I realized there was a mistake in my claim that the smooth approximation $\bar{f}^t$, for some fixed positive integer $t$, is convex for any positive semidefinite matrix $C \in \mathbb{}R^{n \times n}$ and any $s \in \mathbb{R}$. The convexity is a function of both $s$ and $C$ and requires work to be understood to see what actually might work.

Comment: I think you could use the subgradient inequality to get a simpler proof. A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex if and only if $\forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a subgradient $g\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(\mathbf{y})\geq f(\mathbf{x})+g^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})$, for all $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Calculating the subgradients of the function is pretty straight forward, just a matter of manipulating things a bit

Comment: @iarbel84 thanks for the suggestion! It is funny you mention this because I did some googling when I was thinking about this problem and found something mentioning this inequality for showing convexity, but I did not dive into it enough to see how much simpler it could be. I will look into it and see if I can work out a simpler proof than what I wrote down.

Comment: @iarbel84 do you know a reference that proves the statement you mentioned? When I do a quick google, I have not yet seen anyone explicitly mention the statement as an if and only if claim. Still going to look in the meantime, but a reference/link would be helpful!

Comment: https://cims.nyu.edu/~cfgranda/pages/OBDA_fall17/notes/convex_nondifferentiable.pdf Theorem 2.2

Comment: @iarbel84 Thank you so much! I worked out an alternative proof using the subdifferential idea and it was a much simpler proof, as you suspected.

Comment: Happy to help. How did show that there exists a subgradient for which the desired inequality holds?

Comment: @iarbel84 I actually just realized as I was typing it up, I spoke a little too soon about being done. What I decided to do was notice that $\left(\sigma_s(x) - \sigma_s(y)\right)^T C \left(\sigma_s(x) - \sigma_s(y)\right) \geq 0$ which implies that $\sigma_s(x)^T C \sigma_s(x) - \sigma_s(y)^T C \sigma_s(y) \geq 2 \sigma_s(y)^T C ( \sigma_s(x) - \sigma_s(y))$. The only thing I realized I forgot to show is that  $\sigma_s(y)^TC( \sigma_s(x) - \sigma_s(y)) \geq \sigma_s(y)^T C ( x - y )$ (which I hope ends up being true in general). If this is true, then a subgradient can be $g = 2 C\sigma_s(y)$.

Comment: It feels like your last inequality should be true, since by definition $\sigma_s(\mathbf{x})\geq \mathbf{x}$ when taken element-wise.

Comment: @iarbel84 Not sure if this works, unless I made a mistake. If I consider this in $1$-dimensions and set $s = 1$ and $C = 1$, we can choose $y = -1$ and $x = 2$ and find that $\sigma_s(y)(\sigma_s(x) - \sigma_s(y)) = (2 - 1) = 1$ while $\sigma_s(y)(x - y) = (2 - (-1)) = 3$, so this inequality does not work in general I guess.

Comment: You're right about that. Are you confident in the way you reached the inequality? Moreover, maybe the function isn't really convex?

Comment: @iarbel84 well what I can say is that for $s < 0$, I am confident the function is not actually convex. I am reinvestigating using my first approach using $s \geq 0$ to see that this is convex in general, which I feel optimistic about. I will have to circle back to the subdifferential approach after I figured out using my other approach whether the function is convex for $s \geq 0$ or not.

Comment: @iarbel84 on further review, it appears the claim I was trying to make was too general to be true. In fact, I found that the convexity is tied intimately to the value of both $s$ and $C$ and so I cannot make any nice claims like I was hoping to when I first posted.